# Automatically get custom post type data from WordPress

Tags: wordpress, api, automation

I want to set up a webapp that fetches custom post type data from my WordPress database, automatically. With automatically, I mean fetching the data regularly, maybe once every hour, **without me logging in or manually granting my webapp access**. At least not every day.

My first question is whether this can be done with the WordPress REST API? If so, which type of authentication should I implement?

I would love to se an actual example implementation of this use case.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there many custom post types or only one? Rest API can fetch data, without authentication. What you mean to say without me logging in?

Comment: There are multiple cusom post types (and taxonomies).

With "without me logging in", I mean that my webapp needs to be able to fetch the data from my Wordpress database without me logging in to my WordPress account and manually granting my webapp access to the data. Is this possible with the suggested Cookie Authentication? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/